# Best practice for implementing GET operation in Restful service

Tags: web-services, get, jersey

I am trying to find if there is any best practices involved in developing/implementing a GET operation.

I was going through the web resource documentation of jersey.

URL : http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html

If we look at the methods that are available, the 'get' doesn't accept entity.

Is it recommended to implement get operation which doesnt accept entity but only get request parameters from Query Parameters?

Thanks,
GK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Think of the URI as the unique identifier to the object/resource you are GETing. I typically use query params for a GET if required. More normally I just have a GET something like this: GET: https:/myservice.com/myobject/id. This path is usually returned from a PUT or POST operation on MyObject. If I want to look up one or more I then use query params for the criteria.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your feedback/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of best practices out there.  One that seems to bring together most of the common ones in a readable format is provided by Apigee.  You can obtain it from http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing material about best practices!